# Client-side JavaScript validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am new to email validation. Can anybody help me to figure out why it is not working properly. I have a simple form, which contains fields for name, password, confirm password, email and URL. If there is any error in any of these fields, I do not want process the form. If no errors I want to show a message `your form is submitted succesfully`.

[image]

Here is the code.

HTML:

```
<form id='contactForm'>
    <label for='firstAndLastname'></label>
    <input type='text' data-count='0' placeholder='Firstname Lastname' name='firstAndLastname' class='fName' />
    <span></span>

    <label for='password'></label>
    <input type='password' data-count='1' placeholder='Password' name='password' class='password' />
    <span></span>

    <label for='confirmPassword'></label>
    <input type='password'  placeholder='Confirm Password' name='confirmPassword' class='confirmPassword' />
    <span></span>

    <label for='email'></label>
    <input type='email' data-count='2' placeholder='Email' name='email' class='email' />
    <span></span>

    <label for='url'></label>
    <input type='url' data-count='3' placeholder='Website' name='url' class='url' />
    <span></span>

    <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
//url validation
function validateURL(url){
    var urlRegExp = /^(http|https):\/\/(([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:&=]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+@)?(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){3})|localhost|([a-zA-Z0-9\-\u00C0-\u017F]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,}))(:[0-9]+)?(\/(([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*(\/([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*)*)?(\?([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=\/?]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*)?(\#([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),;:@&=\/?]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*)?)?$/;
    return urlRegExp.test(url);
}

//email validation
function validateEmail(email){
    var pattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return pattern.test(email);
}

$('#submit').on('submit', function(e){
    var name = $.trim($('.fName').val()),
    password = $.trim($('.password').val()),
    confirmPassword = $.trim($('.confirmPassword').val()),
    email = $.trim($('.email').val()),
    url = $.trim($('.url').val());

    if (name === '' || password === '' || confirmPassword === '' || email === '' || url==='') {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if($('.password').val() !== $('.confirmPassword').val()) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if(validateEmail($('.email').val() === false)){
        var el = validateEmail($('.email').val());
        console.log(el);
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if(validateURL($('.url').val() === false)){
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        console.log('bar');
        //$('.error-message').fadeIn('slow');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The JS Bin link: http://jsbin.com/dimam/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: can you explain what error, or lack of functionality, you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting error but if i will fill only email and url. and if i will submit then it is submit the form. i do not want that behaviour. i want to check for each input field.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my answer entirely to describe what I did here to make it work:

http://jsfiddle.net/HPLXg/38/

1. you had `;` at the end of your RegExp pattern strings.  These is not necessary for these types of strings.
2. you were binding `submit` on the wrong DOM element.  It needed to be bound on the form not the submit button.
3. since the form is not being added to the DOM dynamically as `live` content, you don't really need to use the `.on()` function, but rather you can simply use the `.submit()` function.
4. I also added other minor cleanups in your if statements:

   - made each check their own if statement rather than an `else if | else` progression, this way each field is checked individually and all errors will display at one time, rather than one error for each time the user clicks submit
   - changed all the `$(..).val()` references in the if statements to use their variables that you already gathered in the variable declaration area of your `.submit()` function.  Not much point in making the values variables if you aren't going to use them...
   - and finally, added some coloring to your errors to indicate which fields are non-compliant with your rules